# SQL: Including 0's in Counts vs Ignoring 0's in Counts?

Tags: sql

I have the following table (called "df"):

```
   name year var1
  John 2010    a
  John 2010    b
  John 2011    a
  John 2011    b
  John 2013    b
  John 2013    b
  Jane 2010    a
  Jane 2010    a
  Jane 2011    b
  Jane 2011    b
```

For each name, I want to count the number of times 'var1 = a' in each year.

**1st Method:** The first way that comes to mind is the "classic" method:

```
  SELECT name, year, SUM(CASE WHEN var1 = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as sum_var1 
  FROM data 
  WHERE var1 = 'a' 
  GROUP BY name, year;
```

The output of this method works - but completely ignores the 2013 year where there are no 'a' values:

```
  name year sum_var1
1 Jane 2010        2
2 John 2010        1
3 John 2011        1
```

**2nd Method:** I tried to think of a "convoluted" way around this problem by joining the table to itself to include these counts

```
WITH p AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT name, year 
  FROM data
)

SELECT p.name, p.year, COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN s.var1 = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) as sum_var1
FROM p
LEFT JOIN data s 
ON p.name = s.name AND p.year = s.year
GROUP BY p.name, p.year;
```

Now, the output is looking at years where no var1 = a:

```
  name year sum_var1
1 Jane 2010        2
2 Jane 2011        0
3 John 2010        1
4 John 2011        1
5 John 2013        0
```

**My Question:** Is there a "simpler" way to deal with this problem that can be done in fewer steps? I feel I am overcomplicating this and there might be a simpler and more standard way to solve this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: `SELECT name, year, SUM(CASE WHEN var1 = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as sum_var1 FROM data GROUP BY name, year;`

Comment: If you have `WHERE var1 = 'a' ` then `CASE WHEN var1 = 'a' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END` will always evaluate to `1` for every row so one or the other is pointless.  But in this case removing the `WHERE` will do what you need

Comment: What would be your desired result? Does #2 do what you want?